# NSIS license page prechecked

Tags: licensing, nsis

I have the following code in an NSIS script...

```
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "eula.txt"
```

... and it works fine. As expected, the user needs to check the "I accept..." `checkbox` and then the install `button` is enabled.

I would like to simplify the process so that the `checkbox` is checked and the install `button` enabled by default and all the user needs to do is install or cancel.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX             ; Tell MUI you want the checkbox version of the license page
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW licshow ; Tell MUI to call a function before the page is displayed
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "eula.txt"     ; Adds the page

Function licshow                             ; Function to be called before the page is displayed
    ; Check it
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT    ; Find the inner dialog (See attached picture)
    GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x40A                   ; Find the checkbox control
    SendMessage $0 ${BM_SETCHECK} 1 0        ; Check the checkbox

    ; Enable button
    GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1              ; Find the Install/Next button
    EnableWindow $0 1                        ; Enable the button
FunctionEnd
```

The last GetDlgItem+EnableWindow commands can be replaced by `SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_COMMAND} 0x40A 0` to simulate the user clicking and would cause NSIS internal processing to enable the button.

---

[image: NSIS inner and outer dialog]

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Why is 0x40A used in both cases? Shouldn't the checkbox and the button have different ids? The function calls make sense to me. How to identify each dialog item does not.

Comment: You can find the ids for standard controls @ https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Source/exehead/resource.h or use a tool like WinSpy++. The WM_COMMAND message takes the id of the control that changed, only NSIS knows that the checkbox is tied to the Next button.

Comment: Wow. It would've never occurred to me. I mean, "WM_COMMAND message takes the id of the control that changed", wow.Thank you, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I got lucky and was able to throw code together from several places.

The following works but I don't really know why NSIS-wise, which I don't like at all. If someone can break it down, I would really, really, appreciate it.

```
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW licshow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "eula.txt"

Function licshow
    ; Check it
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x40A
    SendMessage $0 ${BM_SETCHECK} 1 0

    ; Enable button
    GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
    EnableWindow $0 1
FunctionEnd
```